# Change display format of date in token

Tags: 7, datetime, tokens, quiz

I am using the token for the quiz close date (`[node:quiz:quiz-close]` in a certificate for the quiz module and would like to change the format. I looked at Date & Time in the configuration settings and have already defined a custom one that is just the date (called `just_the_date`).

How can I embed a token for a field that records a more detailed date, but just have it show in my custom format or change the display format for this field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just needed to take the token, `[node:quiz:quiz-close]` and append it with the custom date format machine name `:just_the_date]` to get `[node:quiz:quiz-close:just_the_date]`. Also, it's in the list of tokens, once you expand the date item further.